# How to require NodeJS modules in other JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a nodejs server that connects to mysql database and prints the table in the console which goes as is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "root",
  database: "myarticles"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM articles", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000...');
})
```

This works perfectly, but i would like to be able to load the table (to modify it later) in a separate file. Do I have to specify it in my server file? My other JavsScript file is already loaded with the express module in my server.

Comment: Modularise your code, move the db connection to a new file as a module and use it across your app by merely importing it.

Comment: @varunagarwal with the module.exports function? And then I require it in my server?

Comment: Yes. You can abstract most of your DB logic in that file and all the files can simply do `const DBInstance = require('dbModule');  DBInstance.<OPERATION NAME>`